# Drawing a line in an animated way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, line, render

I'm trying to draw a line between source and destination. Following is my code.

```
public class drawLine : MonoBehaviour
{

    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    private float counter;
    private float dist;

    public Transform origin;
    public Transform destination;
    public float lineDrawSpeed = 6f;
    private float distance;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, origin.transform.position);

        distance = Vector3.Distance(origin.transform.position, destination.transform.position);
        Debug.Log(distance);
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (counter < distance)
        {
            Debug.Log(counter);
            counter += .1f / lineDrawSpeed;
            float x = Mathf.Lerp(0, distance, counter);
            var point0 = origin.transform.position;
            var point1 = destination.transform.position;

            var pointALongLine = x * Vector3.Normalize(point1 - point0) + point0;

            lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, pointALongLine);
        }

    }
}
```

However, the lines are not visible at all even whenthe Debug.Log in update method is being executed. am I missing something?

Comment: do you have a material assigned to the `LineRenderer`?

Comment: yes I have a material asssigned

Comment: hm ... try drawing wire spheres at the points of the line in gizmos just to visually check if the points are where they are expected

Comment: I just tried your script in Unity, and it works fine here. It shows an expanding line from Transform 1 to 2 and draws a line in the assigned material.

Comment: What are your settings for the `Width`? Do have set it to `Alignment = View`? You can simplyfy your code a lot by just using `lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, Vector3.Lerp(origin.transform.position, destination.transform.position, counter / distance));`! This `counter += .1f / lineDrawSpeed;` is **framerate-dependend**! You would rather want to use something like `counter += (0.1f / lineDrawSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;`. Also check if you have `Use World Space` enabled .. otherwise the positions are considered local positions depending on the LineRenderers posiiton, rotation and scale!